# Best way to convert gis data from one postgis table to another for simplification

Tags: database, postgresql, postgis, qgis

I have dumped a lot of shapefiles into a postgis database and will be using this for a GIS application through QGIS. Now, I have developed a data dictionary that is sensible and intuitive for the end user on the trimble gathering data. So this is how the initial table is generated, with end user on trimble being top priority. Now when I use this gathered data in qgis the attribute column that shows up for selected points on some feature classes are not very simplified.

For example, we are a pipeline utility, and I have the trimble set up so that when they select a nominal pipe diameter, it gives options for different wall thicknesses based on that pipe size. This works well on the trimble, but then I get 8 or 9 blank values for every piece of pipe in the map. So if I select a 2" main, the attributes display the size, and wall thickness fields for every size from 3/4" to 10" but the only one that has a value is for the 2". What I would like to do, is create a new table that simplifies this, and then run the data from the table housing the trimble generated data, and dump it into the new table. This will not only require importing the data from one postgres table "Main" in the db "GIS" into a new table "Main" in my trial database, but will also require some code to search through columns a b c d etc. to find the one that that isn't null, and send it to the new table's Wall Thickness column.

I have several properties, and several tables that have these problems, but I think if someone can help or at least point me in the right direction on this particular situation, I can do the rest of them. This is seriously the last step in my GIS build before we are ready to start rolling it out, and I would really appreciate if someone could help me clean this up a bit.

I have pgadmin 4, qgis 2.18, some knowledge on SQL and can manipulate data from the command line, and I see that qgis has a built in python console that may be able to help. I know python a bit, and could probably get by if the best route is through it. Just a bit of information on myself to help you guys determine my best route. Thanks again!

p.s. I have added pictures of my existing data structure for the "Main" feature in qgis, and a picture of the new table I'd like to populate for the "Main" feature in command line. https://i.stack.imgur.com/arUqu.jpg

Comment: what mean `Trimble` ?

Comment: I work with GIS every day, but dont understand your question. Show us db schema, sample data and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: Post the tables and data as text [READ THIS](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7YWtLuKMzjJTTJ2dTNrV2NESG8

Comment: There is a text file containing 1 row of existing data, and what I would like that data to look like in the new table. I apologize, I thought reading the data tables in context would be more helpful than reading a text file. Trimble is a handheld tool for gapturing data used in GIS.

Comment: Still not clear what is the problem. You provide too much context, but I dont know much about pipes so is just noise for me. Provide create table statements, sample data and desire output. Dont provide external link or Images. Use this [**tool**](https://senseful.github.io/web-tools/text-table/) to format the sql tables . And read the links so you can learn how to ask better question

Comment: I have posted the table itself, sample data and desired output in a text format for you. Did you open the google drive link? I read the links, I know what I'm saying. I want to move data from one table into another, and to basically perform a query on the table to gather all of the individual pipe wall thicknesses into one column that has a wall thickness  independent of size. I don't know how to get any clearer than that.

Comment: Yes, I open the file but isn't clear for me what you need. Again, you need three things, Source Data, Current Output and Desire Output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I myself am a pipeline surveyor turned self-taught programmer. So I hope I understand the first part of your dilemma. Each piece of pipe can be of different wall thickness values. Example: mainline pipe is 0.250 and say all the road bore and HDD pipe is 0.300 wall for the heavy wall pipe.
In your query on your 'raw' field data that you have first, can you try something like

```
SELECT * 
FROM your_table
WHERE wall_thickness_value IN (0.250,0.300)
```

Since no pipe would normally have two wall thickness values without some type of transition weld being between them hopefully, this query will grab the actual value for you for that piece of pipe and not return all the nulls.

Comment: FYI, I am no PostgreSQL or programming professional . I have surveyed a lot and been self-studying and teaching myself Java, Python and SQL for a hope in a career change.

Comment: You seem to have it pretty well. I also do not know how to insert these queried values into the other table. So once I have the sql statement to retrieve the values as they should be, how do I get them into the new clean table?

Comment: No worries, I don't care if anyone is a professional. I'm an engineer with autocad experience and when I started at my current company started implementing GIS which I previously had no knowledge on. I'm self taught on everything GIS related so I understand.

Comment: This [link](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-selectinto.html) may help you with that as well.

Comment: Pretty much exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you sir!

Comment: Right on. So glad it helped you out. Good luck with your app and GIS study.